# Rename .jpg files by 'date taken' property in powershell windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell

On windows 10, using PowerShell, I am bulk renaming several .jpg files to be in the format yyyyMMdd+_*(4digitnumber)*+.jpg

A lot of them I've been able to use the last write time property to rename, but for a particular folder, I need to use the 'date taken' property. So far, my code has looked like this:

```
$number = 0001
gci *.jpg -Recurse | 
%{rename-item $_ -newname ($_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyyMMdd")+'_{0:0000}.jpg' -f $number++)}
```

I can't find a way to use the 'date taken' property instead'

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve metadata, such as **Date Taken**, you have to use COM objects:

```
$FOlder = 'c:\pictures\folder'
$CharWhiteList = '[^: \w\/]'
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$i = 1
gci $FOlder *.jpg -Recurse  | ForEach{
    $dir = $Shell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
    $DateTaken = [DateTime]($dir.GetDetailsOf($dir.ParseName($_.Name),12) -replace $CharWhiteList)
    Rename-Item $_.FullName ('{0:yyyyMMdd}_{1:0000}.jpg' -f $DateTaken, $i++) -WhatIf
}
```

[Shell.NameSpace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace)

[Folder.GetDetailsOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-getdetailsof)

[Folder.ParseName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-parsename)